# move_base accuracy thresholds

Tags: ros, navigation, path-planning, global-planner, move-base

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there,

I'm using a turtlebot to do some navigation stuff and have some high level logic that determines where the turtlebot should go (I have regions of interest on my map, and this higher level logic chooses a specific region and decides to move the robot to the centre of the region.).

One of the issues I ran into was when it picks the locations and passes the co-ordinates to the [move_base](http://wiki.ros.org/move_base) server (which seems to be using [global_planner](http://wiki.ros.org/global_planner?distro=hydro)) there is no guarantee that a valid plan can be found for those specific co-ordinates.

What I wanted to know is if there is any way to set a threshold for the accuracy of the planner - in a use case like this it is not actually important that the robot moves to exact co-ordinates specified - being *roughly*  there is good enough.

I was thinking that I could probably just make it keep trying to generate plans by randomly picking new points within a certain radius until it succeeds, but this seemed a little inelegant.

Would appreciate any ideas/pointers on how to get around this issue :)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/203399/move_base-accuracy-thresholds/) by [genericsoup](https://answers.ros.org/users/20987/genericsoup/) on ROS Answers with karma: 45 on 2015-02-18

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

move_base also provides the [make_plan](http://docs.ros.org/api/nav_msgs/html/srv/GetPlan.html) service which allows you to specify a tolerance.

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2015-02-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [genericsoup](https://answers.ros.org/users/20987/genericsoup/) on 2015-02-21**:
Thanks! - this is exactly what I was trying to search for - was just looking in the wrong places!